# Is there a simple way to make a separate checkbox label clickable for a label-hidden lightning-input-field?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

The goal here is to specify a long block of text in an LWC page for a form field rather than to use the field's label. I also want the label to stay clickable, particularly for checkbox fields to avoid users having to home in on just the checkbox.

This for/id pattern (a useful feature of raw HTML) doesn't appear to work:

```
<label
    for="xyz"
    class="slds-form-element__label"
>Custom long label that exceeds the 40 characters of a label field</label>
<lightning-input-field
    id="xyz"
    field-name="Xyz__c"
    variant="label-hidden"
></lightning-input-field>
```

The framework does append e.g. `-28` in both places to ensure the id value is unique.

Before I start adding click handlers to address this, is there a simple declarative solution? My components are LWC not Aura.

Comment: P.S. This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Without knowing what you're actually trying to do, you might not get the answer you want...

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox - thanks, I've made the question more explicit about the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some Googling I came across this post [HTML Inputs and Labels: A Love Story](https://css-tricks.com/html-inputs-and-labels-a-love-story/) that says:

> There are two ways to pair a label and an input. One is by wrapping the input in a label (implicit), and the other is by adding a for attribute to the label and an id to the input (explicit).

The *implicit* approach solves my problem; clicking the label checks the checkbox:

```
<label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__label">
        Custom long label that exceeds the 40 characters of a label field
    </div>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Xyz__c" variant="label-hidden">
     </lightning-input-field>
</label>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that. I might need to review my HTML knowledge, lol.

Comment: @sfdcfox, yeah I read [Jason Knight's blog posts](https://deathshadow.medium.com/) to be reminded that frameworks are not always the answer.